# Issue with jq when using in jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I am having a JSON object x and a variable requiredValue

```
let requiredValue = 5;

let x = [
{"score":1},
{"score":2},
{"score":3}
}
```

Here using jq first i want to extract all score values and then check if any score value in the object is greater than or equal to requiredValue.

Here is what I tried

```
jq -r '.[].score | join(",") | contains([requiredValue])'
```

Suppose if requiredValue is 5 then jq query should return false and if requiredValue is 2 it should return true.

Comment: `let`s aren't JSON syntax, so `jq` can't handle them; `{[...],[...],[...]}` doesn't look like valid JSON to me either. `{"requiredValue": 5, "x": [{"score": 1},{"score":2},{"score":3}]}` would be something it would handle.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes you are right. Now I have correct it. I pasted it wrongly here

Comment: Even as edited, it's still JavaScript, not JSON. You can't have `let`s in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you split your inputs into two valid JSON documents, rather than having a JavaScript input which *is not* valid JSON, you could do the following:

```
requiredValue=5
x='
[{"score":1},
 {"score":2},
 {"score":3}]
'

jq -n \
   --argjson requiredValue "$requiredValue" \
   --argjson x "$x" '
  [$x[].score | select(. == $requiredValue)] | any
'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following has been tested with bash:

```
requiredValue=5

x='[
{"score":1},
{"score":2},
{"score":3}
]'

jq --argjson requiredValue $requiredValue '
  any(.[].score; . >= $requiredValue)' <<< "$x"
```

The result:

```
false
```